# Fade Out only background image not the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade an image as background an I want to fade out only background image not the text.
I want to text stay on the page.
This is what I use:

https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl

Help me please.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  });

/*win.scroll(function(){
  scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
  scrollRatio = 1 - scrollPosition / 300;
  $(".top").css("opacity", scrollRatio);
*/

/*$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollVar = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.top').css("opacity", 1 - scrollVar/300);
})*/
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="title">Fade Away</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you don't want your question to be downvoted please include the code in your question...

Comment: Don't post your code to 3rd party sites. What would happen if your link became dead over time? What would others be able to discern when they came across this question?

Comment: You don't seem to have written any code that attempts to do what you are asking. What have you tried? What problem(s) did you encounter? We are not a code writing service.

Comment: Background image or background colour? There is only colour in your question however the difference here affects the answer

Answer (score 1):

`opacity` affects all content inside an element,you must use `background-color` instead of `opacity`, so:

**Change:**

```
$(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
```

**To:**

```
$(".top").css('background-color', 'rgba(170,170,170,' + (1 - ($(window).scrollTop() / 250)) + ')');
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(".top").css('background-color', 'rgba(170,170,170,' + (1 - ($(window).scrollTop() / 250)) + ')');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top"><div class="title">Fade Away</div></div>
```

***Note:*** I change `color` for `.title` to black,for you to see the result better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another element inside .top and have that fade out instead of fading the outer container:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top-inner").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top-inner {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="top-inner"></div>
  <div class="title">Fade Away</div>
</div>
```